# Error message using "group BY" function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to use `GROUP BY` using Oracle SQL but I'm getting consistently the following error message (in french):

```
"ORA-00979: n'est pas une expression GROUP BY
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

Here is the query i'm using, anyone know what i'm doing wrong?:

```
select id_ws, duration, phases
from from v_cdco_worksite 
left join osi_phases
on v_cdco_worksite.id_ws=osi_phases.id_ws 
group by v_cdco_worksite.id_ws;
```

Comment: `duration, phases` are not part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: But why GROUP BY? (You use no set functions...)

Comment: Its the first time i use group BY so i'm not sure. Basically i want to sum the "phases" column, so the query would look like:

select id_ws, duration, sum (phases)
from from v_cdco_worksite 
left join osi_phases
on v_cdco_worksite.id_ws=osi_phases.id_ws 
group by v_cdco_worksite.id_ws;

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Even by adding these columns in the group by clause i get the same error message

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks it worked in fact, i forgot a column!

Comment: There is also a syntax error in the query posted: `from` is used twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have experience in MySQL, I see.  Oracle does not allow for the use of GROUP BY without an aggregate clause in the select statement.  If you are trying to use GROUP BY as a way to eliminate duplicates, try using DISTINCT in the select statement.  If you are merely trying to order the result set, replace GROUP BY with ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
select v_cdco_worksite.id_ws, sum(duration) SumDuration, sum (phases) SumPhases
from v_cdco_worksite
left join osi_phases on v_cdco_worksite.id_ws=osi_phases.id_ws
group by v_cdco_worksite.id_ws;
```

Since id_ws is in both tables you need to specify WHICH one you want and of course WHICH one to group by. Furthermore you forgot to either put the duration into the group by as well or to sum ist up as you did with phases. Hope this helps.

Comment: So, judging by the "unaccept" I guess the proposed solution didn't work? Do you still receive an error?